# Invalid User vs. User Not Allowed in ssh log

Tags: ssh, users

When looking at the `auth.log`:

From a security perspective, what is the difference between "Invalid User" and "User Not allowed because not listed in "AllowUsers."

Examples:

```
Nov  6 10:42:37 ePVPNDMZ01X sshd[12598]: Invalid user cni07 from <IP Address>
Nov  4 07:28:15 ePVPNDMZ01X sshd[2722]: User root from <IP Address> not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
```

Answer (score 3):

Invalid user means the ssh request was made by a user name on the system, "cni07" in this case. There is no user "cni07"

User not allowed means there is a user, "root" in this case, but that user is not allowed to log in via ssh. This could be restricted by a variety of means in the sshd_config file.